# Get UTF-8 equivalent of a Wingdings character

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, fonts, utf

**The Problem**

I'm developing a **PHP** application which displays **Wingdings** and **Webdings** characters. If I Just put a font-tag around it, the character gets displayed correctly. Though, once it gets **copy-pasted** it reverts to the character it was before like "a".

**What I think would be the Solution**

This problem could be solved by escaping every wingdings character on the page by the UTF-8 equivalent. UTF-8 holds so many characters, so I'm guessing that Wingings characters and the like are also on that list.

**Question**

How can I map/create UTF-8 characters from Wingdings characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of equivalent unicode characters to wingdings.
Is this, what you are looking for?

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Comment: Technically, yes. I stumbled upon that site during my research. I also copied characters from it but forgot to set my editor to UTF-8 so I didn't see that it is actually working. This list should give me a start. Thank you!

Comment: alanwood site is nice but I need the same table for Wingdings 3 and Webdings. Do you know any such site?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak This document should work:
https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2012/12368-n4384.pdf
To translate any character: Look at section 1 to get wingdings-id. Then look in section 3 for that wingdings-id. E.g. wingdings3 left dashed arrow has value 0x33 (51), so wingdings-id 3051. Searching that id in section 3 gives u+2b6a, and mentions u+21e0 as an alternative. Both are nice left dashed arrows.